# Call a Finite State Machine in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, state-machines

I need to read data from a SRAM in one step (something like READ_RAM(addr) that returns the value stored in the SRAM at the "addr" address).
Is it possible create a function/procedure that integrates a Finite State Machine?

Answer (score 1):

A FSM is a sequential piece of circuitry, and functions are combinational only, so a function cannot represent by itself a FSM.  However, the combinational paths of the FSM can be represented with functions.  Typical examples are coding the next state or the outputs based on the current state and inputs.  It is a very clean way of coding a FSM.

A procedure, on the other hand, can contain sequential statements, but when they do they are mostly used for testbenches using `wait` statements, which are not synthesizable.

Comment: I have also created a SRAM controller entity but the controller needs signal like Memory Request and after the start of the reading I need to wait X clock cycles before the data is available. How can I wait that the reading is ended?

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  If your latency is constant, after starting the read then have a counter count up to `X` (or `X-1`), and when it reaches this value grab the data output by your SRAM controller.  If the latency is not constant, the controller must have some kind of `validdata` signal that you can poll.

Comment: I have a MemReady signal but how can I wait on this signal? The WAIT statement cannot be synthesized and the READ_RAM operations are executed in a process so I can't use a clock counter variable.

Comment: You can use a FSM (coded as a process).  When you are waiting for `MemReady` you enter a state, call it something like `st_waitingForMemReady`, and to get out of that state  you check the value of `MemReady`.  Something like `if MemReady = '1' then next_state <= st_doneReading; end if;`

Comment: The problem is that I can't exit from the current clock cycle of the process without that I have read the RAM. If I exit from this clock cycle I lose the current pixel and pass to the next.

Comment: This is difficult to answer in a comment, especially without knowing the architecture of your design.  I suggest you create another question with the specifics of your design and explaining what the issue is.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will create a new question with more specifics as you suggested.